# How to pass CSS variable in background URL

Tags: html, css

I need to pass an image to the CSS background like this it works:

```
.tinted-image {
  height: 125px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--color), var(--color2)),
    url(https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Apex%20Legends-300x400.jpg);
}
```

but when I try to do it like this, I get a syntax error in VS Code

```
.tinted-image {
      height: 125px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--color), var(--color2)),
        url(var(--url));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it like the following:

```css
:root {
  --color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  --color2: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  --url: url(https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Apex%20Legends-300x400.jpg);
}
.tinted-image {
  height: 125px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--color), var(--color2)), var(--url);
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tinted-image"></div>
```

CSS variables doesn't work on Internet Explorer. You can find all browsers with CSS variable support here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: how to change the URL dynamically using CSS var for multi-theme?

Comment: It doesn't work in IE